# converting .__comobj WIA to byte[] in C# application

Tags: c#, byte, workflow-foundation, scanning, wia

I have the following code in my C# application.  I want it to capture a scanning document using WIA into a byte[] variable, but i couldn't convert the `.__comobject` into byte[]

```
private void btnScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var deviceManager = new DeviceManager();

                DeviceInfo AvailableScanner = null;

                for (int i = 1; i <= deviceManager.DeviceInfos.Count; i++) // Loop Through the get List Of Devices.
                {
                    if (deviceManager.DeviceInfos[i].Type != WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType) // Skip device If it is not a scanner
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    AvailableScanner = deviceManager.DeviceInfos[i];

                    break;
                }

                var device = AvailableScanner.Connect(); //Connect to the available scanner.
                var ScanerItem = device.Items[1]; // select the scanner.
                var imgFile = ScanerItem.Transfer(FormatID.wiaFormatJPEG); //Retrive an image in Jpg format and store it into a variable.


                TypeConverter obj = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(imgFile.GetType());
                byte[] bt = (byte[])obj.ConvertTo(imgFile, typeof(byte[]));
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bt);
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

                //PictureBox1.Image = img;
            }
            catch(COMException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is it just use WIA.ImageFile then convert it using FileData.get_BinaryData():

```
WIA.ImageFile imagefile = item.Transfer(format) as WIA.ImageFile;
byte[] imageBytes = (byte[])imagefile.FileData.get_BinaryData();
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.