# how to display image in picturebox without saving in local file system in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```cs
//Retrieve an image in Jpg format and store it into a variable.
var imgFile = (ImageFile)ScanerItem.Transfer(FormatID.wiaFormatJPEG);  
                            
var Path = @"D:\ScanImg.jpg";   

// save the image in some path with filename.
imgFile.SaveFile(Path);

pictureBox1.ImageLocation = Path;
```

Comment: Is the `asp.net` tag correct? Or did you mean `winforms`? There is no `PictureBox` in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the following SO answer, you can get the `byte[]` of the image with `(byte[])imgFile.FileData.get_BinaryData()`:

[converting .__comobj WIA to byte[] in C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58681540/converting-comobj-wia-to-byte-in-c-sharp-application)

A bitmap can be put as source into the PictureBox.
Therefore the `byte[]` as to put into a `MemoryStream` and create a `Bitmap`:

```
var imgFile = (ImageFile)ScanerItem.Transfer(FormatID.wiaFormatJPEG);  
byte[] imageBytes = (byte[])imgFile.FileData.get_BinaryData();
Bitmap image;

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
{
   image = new Bitmap(stream);
}
pictureBox1.Image = image;
```